# Why did the real Captain Jack Harkness in 1941 kiss Captain Jack Harkness?

Tags: torchwood

I remember Captain Jack Harkness encouraged the real Captain Jack Harkness to savor the moment before the next day (during which he would die.) Then the real Captain Jack Harkness tried to hold hands with Captain Jack Harkness, and they ended-up kissing passionately.

We've seen Captain Jack Harkness kiss Jack Hart and Ianto also.  Are they gay?

Comment: "gay" is such an old fasioned third-millenium concept.

Answer (score 9):

[Jack](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_Harkness) is Omnisexual, and, at least to some degree, has been seen to provoke a response even from people who otherwise would not be attracted to his gender.  (Straight men, possibly lesbian women (I don't remember seeing such, but it wouldn't surprise me), etc.)  As I recall, Ianto wasn't gay (with anyone else/the rest of his life).. He just responded to Jack.

That being said, the Doctor Who Wiki lists [Captain Jack](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_Harkness_%28Captain_Jack_Harkness%29) (the real one) as a homosexual trapped in a heterosexual relationship; I don't remember this being explicitly laid out, but it's pretty strongly implied.

Comment: Any for completeness: Ianto is not gay, in that he is not attracted to "men" but specifically, and *only*, to "Jack Harkness".

Comment: I thought it was spelled out as much as they could that  the real Captain Jack was gay without actually having someone say, "Oh, that Captain Jack is gay."

Comment: @TangoOversway - Exactly; they make it pretty obvious, but without explicitly stating it in so many words.  That being said, it's not that surprising that it was not stated; culturally speaking, at that time and place, it wasn't that uncommon, but being 'known' would have caused him a lot of problems.